# Angular - Async Pipe - Template Binding Behavior

Tags: angular, asynchronous, pipe, templatebinding

I am binding an observable to my Angular template and having conditional binding to show 'loading..' message till async pipe resolves the data.

The binding works fine and i am getting the data and the 'loading..' message getting triggered till i get the data.

```
<div *ngIf=" (combinedResult$ | async )  as favData ;else  loading"> 
   <p> {{ Binding Goes here}} </p>
</div>

<ng-template #loading>
       loading...   
</ng-template>
```

but if i change *ngIf by wrapping the result into "details:" object, then the if condition is not working and i could not see the 'loading..' message. ( But data is binding ).

```
 <div *ngIf=" { details: (combinedResult$ | async ) } as favData  
   ;else  loading">

      <p> {{ Binding Goes here}} </p>

  </div>
```

What am i missing here..?

Comment: Is `details` your component variable?

Comment: @dlieepkumar - Even if i declare it inside the component , still the same result.

Comment: Why do you want to assign the value in the `details`?

Comment: @dlieepkumar -Opps! You are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this, `*ngIf="{ details: (combinedResult$ | async ) } as favData; else  loading"`

`{ details: (combinedResult$ | async ) }` always evaluates to true as it is not a condition but an assignment.

So it will never show the loading as the ngIf always evaluates to **true**